# How to save default values into an option and delete those upon actvation and deactivation in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I ma using Settings API to save and delete values to and from the options I created! But it is not working. Can someone point out to me why it is not working? Here is the code:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'twmm_activate'); //activate plugin options open activation of plugin
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'twmm_deactivate'); //deactivate plugin options open deactivation of plugin
function twmm_activate() {
  $defaults_twmm = array(
    'twmm_on_off' => 'disabled',
    'twmm_middle_layout_selector' => 'email',
  );
  foreach ($defaults_twmm as $key => $value) {
    update_option($key, $value);
  }
}
function twmm_deactivate() {
  delete_option('twmm_options'); //delete plugin specific options upon deactivation
}
```

Comment: you create two options named `twmm_on_off` and `twmm_middle_layout_selector`, you then try to delete an option named `twmm_options`.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. I am deleting the option in deactivation hook. So the option will be deleted when the user deactivates the plugin right?

Comment: you are trying to delete an option with a name that doesn't match the names of either of the options you created.

Comment: oh wait, so I have to use the key instead of the option name from `register_setting('twmm_options_group', 'twmm_options', 'twmm_options_validation');`?

Comment: @Milo I tried, but didn't work. Its the same, default values not getting set!

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked. According to the comment by Milo, I have been doing it wrong by using the option name. So instead I used each keys from the option and used the array to pass the defaults. Thanks milo! :_

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'twmm_activate'); //activate plugin options open activation of plugin
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'twmm_deactivate'); //deactivate plugin options open deactivation of plugin
function twmm_activate() {
  $defaults_twmm = array(
    'twmm_on_off' => 'disabled',
    'twmm_middle_layout_selector' => 'email',
    'twmm_permission_lvl' => 'admin',
    'twmm_page_title' => 'We will be back',
    'twmm_custom_message' => 'Please check back after some time. <br />Thank you!',
    'twmm_facebook' => 'http://facebook.com/techtuft',
    'twmm_twitter' => 'http://twitter.com/techtuft',
  );
  $options = wp_parse_args(update_option('twmm_options', $defaults_twmm));
}
function twmm_deactivate() {
  delete_option('twmm_on_off'); //delete plugin specific options upon deactivation
  delete_option('twmm_middle_layout_selector');
  delete_option('twmm_permission_lvl');
  delete_option('twmm_page_title');
  delete_option('twmm_custom_message');
  delete_option('twmm_facebook');
  delete_option('twmm_twitter');
}
```